# Limit entries number on network/sites.php

Tags: multisite, filters, admin

in order to limit the memory usage of my page, I need to limit the entries number on the page sites.php (for network management)

I tried to a filter with `$pagenow == sites.php` but that didnt work.
I found a filter to restrict the sortable columns `('manage_sites-network_sortable_columns')` but nothing to limit the number or item per page.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd be surprised if the site listing page used a lot of memory? Even if it loads a dozen entries from wp_options per site it's listing then that can only be a few K each.

Comment: This page contain some customs columns with proxy connexion and live status on some server.